# Python Threading and Input

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am new to Python `threading` and I need some help with some code, I am working on making an IRC client as a hobby but I need the ability for the user to be able to input text and also pull messages from the IRC server, etc.

In this example, whilst getting user input, the `.`'s are being outputted after the text that the user has entered I would like the input to be separate to what is being outputted in the listen function.

```
import threading
import time
import sys


def listen():
    sys.stdout.write("Listening...")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.write(".")
        sys.stdout.flush()
    return

def test_input():
    input("Here: ")
    return

threads = []
listen_thread = threading.Thread(target=listen)
threads.append(listen_thread)
listen_thread.start()

input_thread = threading.Thread(target=test_input)
threads.append(input_thread)
input_thread.start()
```

Currently, if I type 'hello there how are you' I get: `Listening...Here: .hell.o there. how ar.e you.`

I would like `Listening........ Here: hello there how are you`
with the `.`'s after the 'Listening'

(Sorry about the wording)

Comment: Its not very clear what you want to achieve. You want the dots to appear over a 5 second time period, but you also don't want to wait for the user to input text. You could save the inputted text and print it after the initial 'animation' is finished.

Comment: @PaulRooney I want the dots to appear over 5 seconds but also be able to take user input at the same time without either being interrupted. (The Listening... is supposed to illustrative and would actually wait for pushed messages from IRC)

Comment: The two are bound to mingle if you write them at the same time. The only way I see to counter this is to either treat both as one string and combine them on each refresh, you could write them on separate lines using something like `ncurses` (but I'm not sure you want to go there) or go gui using tkinter or pyqt.

Comment: @PaulRooney I don't think I'll be able to do it then because wanted was a user list down the side of the screen, messages on the left and chatbox at the bottom left (like [freenode](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/authors/jeffreyway/freenodeweb2.png) irc client )

Comment: @PaulRooney Actually, I think I'll go with a GUI (and learn) Tkinter looks quite outdated though.

Answer (score 0):

You immediately start the test_input() thread after starting the listen() thread. And because the test_input() thread runs in parallel you immediately print "Here".
You should call a.start() only after having printed all the dots. (which takes 5 seconds).

Also try to use more descriptive variable names.

Comment: Is it possible that I don't have to wait to get the user's input?

Comment: Currently I don't see any code that waits and/or checks if a user has given any input.